# Settings different Values of element on a state

Tags: react-native

So in my react native, I have a spinner which I am using to enter numbers. It has two buttons which increases or decreases a value. But the problem is that I have to set the value to a state and I have multiple elements. So if I change the value of one element, everything else changes too.

Here is the [Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-input-spinner)

And here is a sample code I am working with:

```
this.state = {
 qty: null,
}

<InputSpinner
    max={50}
    min={1}
    step={1}
    width={100}
    height={50}
    colorMax={"#2a292d"}
    colorMin={"#2a292d"}
    buttonFontSize={13}
    value={this.state.qty}
    onChange={(num) => {
    this.setState({qty: num});
 }}/>
```

So on change I am settings the `qty` state. But I have multiple spinners and changing one changes everything because each uses the same state. What would be the better solution for this? Should I use an array to store each item qty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the better solution is assign at each Spinner an ID and then create an object with `key = spinnerID` and `value = num`

```
this.state = {
 qty: {},
}

<InputSpinner
    max={50}
    min={1}
    step={1}
    width={100}
    height={50}
    colorMax={"#2a292d"}
    colorMin={"#2a292d"}
    buttonFontSize={13}
    value={this.state.qty['1'] || 1}
    onChange={(num) => {
    let qty = Object.assign({}, this.state.qty);
    qty['1'] = num;
    this.setState({qty});
 }}/>
```

Comment: Can I use this with axios API requests? I want to send the value to an axios request as well. What shall I do in that case

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for! My axios requests are easier with this. So I just pass in my iterated item ID instead of `qty['1']` so it becomes `qty[i.id]` and now in my axios, I can get the state value according to the item ID. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: it's indeed better than array

Answer (score 1):

yes, obviously you need to maintain multiple states for each spinner, never use one state for that. I would recommend to use an array like

```
`
this.state = {
spinnerValues:[]
}
`
```

and  onChange of that input spinner you can do somewhat like

```
`
 onChange={(num) => {
let currentState = this.state.spinnerValues;
currentState[i] = num; // here  i is the index which you will provide for the spinner num
    this.setState({spinnerValues: currentState});
`
```

and for value of each spinner

`value = {this.state.spinnerValues[i]}`

Comment: Unfortunately the result is the same. All the values changes are same

Comment: The same thing you are doing. A copy and paste of your example. The only difference is the `}}` on the on change to close it. Other than that, everything is the same